# How to use CommunityToolkit.Maui DrawingView inside of a Maui Blazor App

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-community-toolkit

I'm new to Maui Blazor, using it as I'm more comfortable with Razor pages from my MVC days than XAML.  I've created the default Maui Blazor application in VS 2022 and it seems to generate one XAML file that points to the Blazor stuff like so:

```
<BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
    <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
    </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
</BlazorWebView>
```

However all the examples of using the DrawingView from the community toolkit (i'm using version 2.0 to support .net 6) seem to be with XAML and not Blazor, like so:

> 3. Add the namespace in your Xaml:
>
> xmlns:views="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"

> 4. Finally, consume it in your Xaml like below:
>
>    ```
>         <views:DrawingView
>             x:Name="DrawView"
>             BackgroundColor="LightGray"
>             WidthRequest="200"
>             HeightRequest="200"
>             IsMultiLineModeEnabled="True"
>             LineColor="Red"
>             LineWidth="1"
>             HorizontalOptions="Center" />
>    ```

Can someone show me how to use the Drawing View in my .razor implementation instead of in the XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.NET MAUI Community Toolkit` is a collection of reusable elements for application development with [.NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/?view=net-maui-7.0), including animations, behaviors, converters, effects, and helpers. In `.NET MAUI Blazor`, I tried to use the `Drawing View` in `.razor page`. Unfortunately, it failed to render the `Drawing View` like in [.NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/drawingview).

I would suggest that you can [open a New Feature Proposal](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/new?assignees=&labels=new%2Cproposal&template=open-a-new-feature-proposal.yml&title=%5BProposal%5D+) on Github to propose a suggestion on supporting the `Drawing View` in `.razor page`.

Comment: so when you say: "Unfortunately, it failed to render the Drawing View like in .NET MAUI.", do you mean it also failed in non-blazor .net maui? Or do you mean it failed to render successfully like it did in maui? I haven't tried it there yet but i've seen working examples...

Comment: It can render successfully in MAUI however failed to work in .razor NET MAUI Blazor.