# How do I make a modal multi-window in .NET Maui?

Tags: modal-dialog, maui, winui-3, maui-blazor

I'm opening a second Window in .NET Maui via `Application.Current.OpenWindow()`, and was wondering if there was a solution to make this second Window "modal" (e.g. the second window must be closed before you can interact with the parent window again). I've been doing a bit of research online and ran into a few deadends. I'm still learning in the process of learning about Maui, Blazor, and XAML, so I appreciate your understanding if I jumble some of the terms.

In my Razor component (DialogueTest.razor), I made this function to launch a second window.

```
public void ModalWindowLaunch()
   {
       Window secondWindow = new Window()
           {
               Page = new WindowPage(),
           };
       Application.Current.OpenWindow(secondWindow);
   }
```

This function uses a class, WindowPage, I created that inherits from ContentPage

`public partial class WindowPage : ContentPage`

In this class, I added the following code based on this [Microsoft Learn post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1341122/maui-windows-and-sizes).

```
var mauiWindow = this.Window.Handler.VirtualView;
var nativeWindow = this.Window.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.Maui.MauiWinUIWindow;
nativeWindow.Activate();
IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
var windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
var p = appWindow.Presenter as Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter;
p.IsModal = true;
```

However, I get an exception: "The window should have an owner when IsModal=true". I have been unable to find any leads on how to assign ownership to the parent window in Maui, as it seems [ownership needs to be assigned at creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.appwindow.create?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#microsoft-ui-windowing-appwindow-create(microsoft-ui-windowing-appwindowpresenter-microsoft-ui-windowid)), but Application.Current.OpenWindow is creating the window without ownership (could be wrong on this).

I also tried `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new WindowPage());` but this does not display the parent window while the new Page object is pushed onto the modal stack (a behavior I'd like to avoid, I want both windows to be visible, with the parent being non-interactive)

Is my approach incorrect? Should I disabling / freezing the parent window via Maui instead of trying to make changes with the WinUI? Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wondering if there was a solution to make this second Window "modal"
> (e.g. the second window must be closed before you can interact with
> the parent window again).

At first I wanted to use [`Popup of .NET MAUI Community Toolkit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) to implement, but [it cannot be used in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75852377/19902734).

However, you can use the following code to achieve it:

Create a [MAUI Blazor project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhpsf.png) and then add a `Razor Component` named: Modalpopuplayout.razor:

```xml
@inherits LayoutComponentBase


@Body


@code {


}
```

For Index.razor, change to this:

```cs
@page "/"
@layout Modalpopuplayout
<button @onclick="()=>{ispopup=true;}" class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Show Modal</button>


@if (ispopup)
{
    <div class="modal fade show" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-1" style="display: block;    background-color: #0000005c;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
                    <button type="button" @onclick="()=>{ispopup=false;}" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>The content of your modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-light" @onclick="()=>{ispopup=false;}" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}

@code {
    bool ispopup = false;
    }
```

Run the project and here is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjvOq.png).

In addition, You can also refer to the solution of this case: [Creating a popup in Blazor using C# method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72005336/19902734).